# How could I hide the minimap bar on sublimetext 3

Tags: sublimetext3

It takes too much space on the window,

I tried some option in the configuration

It seems not working, any idea ?

## User setting

```
"draw_minimap_border": false,
"draw_minimap": false,
"hide_minimap": true,
"always_show_minimap_viewport": false
```

[image: inline]

Answer (score 68):

Click on `View` (check the mouse arrow/pointer in below image) on top menu bar or hit `Alt` + `V` and click `Hide Minimap`[image]

Comment: Can it be hidden by default, which is what I think this question was asking?

Comment: Once you perform this settings, this will remain as it is until you change it, regardless of whatever operations is performed on Sublime text

Comment: @SohelAhmedM it doesn't remain as default

Comment: @HassanAzimi please see my above comment

Comment: @SohelAhmedM I've seen it already. Still will not remain as default!

Comment: Open only one sublime instance, set `View`->`Hide Minimap` and close it. Then it worked for me (v3.2.1 Ubuntu 18.04).

Comment: It's annoying though that Sublime is steering away from the JSON configuration towards GUI based configuration.

Answer (score 28):

I added a shortcut on Sublime Text 3.

Go to `Preferences` -> `Key Bindings`. In user key bindings I added:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+f2"], "command": "toggle_minimap" },
]
```

Obviously you can choose another key combination.

Comment: I find `"ctrl+k", "ctrl+m"` is a nice combo, as `"ctrl+k", "ctrl+b"` is the default for toggling the side bar

Comment: `{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+m"], "command": "toggle_minimap" }`

Comment: This is the real answer

Answer (score 24):

I don't believe there's a setting in Sublime Text 3 to hide the minimap by default.

[This](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/hide-minimap-for-certain-filetypes/24557/3) solution has worked perfectly for me, however:

Save the following Python code as `minimap_setting.py` in the User directory (in Preferences -> Browse Packages):

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class MinimapSetting(sublime_plugin.EventListener):

    def on_activated(self, view):
        show_minimap = view.settings().get('show_minimap')
        if show_minimap:
            view.window().set_minimap_visible(True)
        elif show_minimap is not None:
            view.window().set_minimap_visible(False)
```

Then, you just add `"show_minimap": false` in your settings and you're good to go.

Answer (score 19):

`Ctrl+Shift+p` to open the command palette, then type in `minimap`.

[image]

Comment: The command palette solution is such a quick fix! I love when sublime uses the command palette!

Comment: Such an elegant approach. Still today it works for Sublime 4. This should be accepted as the right answer. Thanks and up-vote :)

Answer (score 6):

It's very easy in Sublime text 3. To hide Minimap:

> View  > Hide Minimap

Answer (score 2):

Check your default settings; `Preferences` -> `Settings - Default`. If a setting is not listed there, your version of sublime will **not** handle overriding it in `Settings - User` - Don't waste your time.

Check if the latest version of sublime has settings you can override - http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/settings.html

On the latest sublime for me, I can't hide tabs, the minimap or the status bar via user settings - just by manually disabling them in the menu dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

Just use package and once for all.

Tools > Command Palette > Package Control: Install Package > Search `Close​Minimap​On​Multi​View` and install. It will close all minimap for all windows.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can disable on **View** menu clicking on **Hide Minimap**.

Answer (score 0):

On SublimeText 3, I can see F2 Keymap, easier, isn't it?